# Efficient implementation of natural logarithm (ln) and exponentiation

Tags: c, math, microcontroller

I'm looking for implementation of `log()` and `exp()` functions provided in C library `<math.h>`. I'm working with 8 bit microcontrollers (OKI 411 and 431). I need to calculate [Mean Kinetic Temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_kinetic_temperature). The requirement is that we should be able to calculate MKT as fast as possible and with as little code memory as possible. The compiler comes with `log()` and `exp()` functions in `<math.h>`. But calling either function and linking with the library causes the code size to increase by 5 Kilobytes, which will not fit in one of the micro we work with (OKI 411), because our code already consumed ~12K of available ~15K code memory.

The implementation I'm looking for should not use any other C library functions (like pow(), sqrt() etc). This is because all library functions are packed in one library and even if one function is called, the linker will bring whole 5K library to code memory.

EDIT

The algorithm should be correct up to 3 decimal places.

Comment: When you have such limitations, you should be also asking yourself what is the precision you can accept ? So what's the acceptable error margin ?

Comment: @YochaiTimmer: forgot to add. thanks for reminding. i've edited my question. :)

Comment: Also, what are the input and output numeric formats? Fixed-point such as 8.8? It sounds like you would benefit by storing an offset relative to 273 kelvins, i.e. Celsius.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: the input/output is not any concern. what do you mean by 'bias relative to 273K'?

Comment: @Donotalo Because 273 is a large number relative to the value of the temperature in Celsius, you can get more precision from the same bits by storing Celsius instead of Kelvin. Actually this illustrates why the input/output *is* a concern. As Alexei mentions, the temperature range affects the choice of formula.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating logarithm function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862699/creating-logarithm-function-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Taylor series for e^x converges extremely quickly, and you can tune your implementation to the precision that you need. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)

The Taylor series for log is not as nice...

Comment: if my calculations are correct, the input for `ln` will be in range [0.94, 0.98]. i guess taylor series is good enough for approximation for `ln` too.

Comment: @Donotalo I'm late to the party here. Just be aware that the range you specified is in the "not nice" part of the Taylor series for the natural logarithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Series

Comment: @Eddy: The Taylor series approach is not efficient since the convergence is slow. 
Instead, use Newton's method, which has cubic convergence to ln(x). 
[See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63773160/155077)

Answer (score 23):

Using Taylor series is not the simplest neither the fastest way of doing this. Most professional implementations are using approximating polynomials. I'll show you how to generate one in [Maple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maple_(software)) (it is a computer algebra program), using the [Remez algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm).

For 3 digits of accuracy execute the following commands in Maple:

```
with(numapprox):
Digits := 8
minimax(ln(x), x = 1 .. 2, 4, 1, 'maxerror')
maxerror
```

Its response is the following polynomial:

```
-1.7417939 + (2.8212026 + (-1.4699568 + (0.44717955 - 0.056570851 * x) * x) * x) * x
```

With the maximal error of: 0.000061011436

[image: Remez approximation of a function]

We generated a polynomial which approximates the ln(x), but only inside the [1..2] interval. Increasing the interval is not wise, because that would increase the maximal error even more. Instead of that, do the following decomposition:

[image: formula]

So first find the highest power of 2, which is still smaller than the number (See: [What is the fastest/most efficient way to find the highest set bit (msb) in an integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i)). That number is actually the base-2 logarithm. Divide with that value, then the result gets into the 1..2 interval. At the end we will have to add n*ln(2) to get the final result.

An example implementation for numbers >= 1:

```
float ln(float y) {
    int log2;
    float divisor, x, result;

    log2 = msb((int)y); // See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4970859/6630230
    divisor = (float)(1 << log2);
    x = y / divisor;    // normalized value between [1.0, 2.0]

    result = -1.7417939 + (2.8212026 + (-1.4699568 + (0.44717955 - 0.056570851 * x) * x) * x) * x;
    result += ((float)log2) * 0.69314718; // ln(2) = 0.69314718

    return result;
}
```

Although if you plan to use it only in the [1.0, 2.0] interval, then the function is like:

```
float ln(float x) {
    return -1.7417939 + (2.8212026 + (-1.4699568 + (0.44717955 - 0.056570851 * x) * x) * x) * x;
}
```

Comment: What would be the implementation for numbers between ]0,1] ?

Comment: @ThadeuAntonioFerreiraMelo : I would estimate ]0; 1] with another polynomial, and use an if/else statement to decide which to use. This is that polynomyal (for this low precision): `-8.6731532+(129.946172+(-558.971892+(843.967330-409.109529*x)*x)*x)*x`

Comment: Actually you can find why this isn't selected as right answer. 
+ with some search one can find ready to go implementation in mathematics sun library implementation (msun).

Comment: Apologies; I downvoted your answer because the code didn't work on a C++ playground I tried it on. I have since tried it in Visual Studio, where it worked; but I cannot change my vote; it says "your vote is locked in." I do not know how to fix this.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need floating-point math for anything else, you may compute an approximate fractional base-2 log pretty easily.  Start by shifting your value left until it's 32768 or higher and store the number of times you did that in `count`.  Then, repeat some number of times (depending upon your desired scale factor):

```
n = (mult(n,n) + 32768u) >> 16; // If a function is available for 16x16->32 multiply
count<<=1;
if (n < 32768) n*=2; else count+=1;
```

If the above loop is repeated 8 times, then the log base 2 of the number will be count/256.  If ten times, count/1024.  If eleven, count/2048.  Effectively, this function works by computing the integer power-of-two logarithm of n**(2^reps), but with intermediate values scaled to avoid overflow.

Comment: There is a small bug in the above algorithm:
After shifting the value, count has to be replaced with 15 - count.
Aside from that, is there a more detailed explanation of the algorithm?

Comment: Does this algorithm have a name?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I don't know of a name for it.  I devised it when I needed to measure the RC time constant of a circuit given two ADC readings taken a known time apart (compute the log of each reading, and take take the scaled reciprocal of the difference), but I'd be shocked if I was the first to use that approach.  To see what the algorithm is doing, it may be helpful to consider what would happen if it used arbitrary-precision integers and instead of shifting n right by 16 bits each time, it shifted the 32768 left by 16 bits.

Comment: The goal of the function is then to find the value of `count` such that if `n0` is the starting value of `n`, `n0**rounds * 2**count` would be in the range `2**(16*rounds-1) and `2**(16*rounds)-1`.

Comment: I didn't do any formal analysis of the worst-case error bounds for this general approach, but since the input was a 16-bit value I simply wrote a program to test all 65535 input values and confirmed that the result was within tolerance (+/-1 IIRC) for all of them.

Comment: In case you're not aware of the reason for the renewed interest in this answer: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30952/how-did-the-apollo-computers-evaluate-transcendental-functions-like-sine-arctan/31050#31050

Comment: @m69: I'd seen the sine/cos there, but not the log.  I suppose a simplified description of my algorithm is that it tries to estimate how many shifts would be required to normalize n**(2**reps) without having to compute the intermediate products to full precision.  By the description, it sounds like the AGC used a similar approach.

Answer (score 7):

Necromancing. 
I had to implement logarithms on rational numbers.

This is how I did it:

Occording to Wikipedia, there is the [Halley-Newton approximation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#High_precision)

[image: Halley-Newton Method]

which can be used for very-high precision.

Using Newton's method, the iteration simplifies to (implementation), which has cubic convergence to ln(x), which is way better than what the Taylor-Series offers.

```
// Using Newton's method, the iteration simplifies to (implementation) 
// which has cubic convergence to ln(x).
public static double ln(double x, double epsilon)
{
    double yn = x - 1.0d; // using the first term of the taylor series as initial-value
    double yn1 = yn;

    do
    {
        yn = yn1;
        yn1 = yn + 2 * (x - System.Math.Exp(yn)) / (x + System.Math.Exp(yn));
    } while (System.Math.Abs(yn - yn1) > epsilon);

    return yn1;
}
```

This is not C, but C#, but I'm sure anybody capable to program in C will be able to deduce the C-Code from that.

Furthermore, since

> logn(x) = ln(x)/ln(n).

You have therefore just implemented logN as well.

```
public static double log(double x, double n, double epsilon)
{
    return ln(x, epsilon) / ln(n, epsilon);
}
```

where epsilon (error) is the minimum precision.

Now as to speed, you're probably better of using the ln-cast-in-hardware, but as I said, I used this as a base to implement logarithms on a rational numbers class working with arbitrary precision.

Arbitrary precision might be more important than speed, under certain circumstances.

Then, use the [logarithmic identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Logarithmic_identities) for rational numbers:
logB(x/y) = logB(x) - logB(y)

Here you go for the C-version:

```
// compile with: gcc loga.c -lm -o loga

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double ln(double x, double epsilon)
{
    double yn = x - 1.0; // using the first term of the Taylor series as initial-value
    double yn1 = yn;

    do
    {
        yn = yn1;
        yn1 = yn + 2 * (x - exp(yn)) / (x + exp(yn));
    } while (fabs(yn - yn1) > epsilon);

    return yn1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double x = 2.0; // You can change the values as needed
    double epsilon = 1e-6;
    double result = ln(x, epsilon);

    printf("ln(%lf) = %lf\n", x, result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this code is its using another function `exp`

Comment: You can always implement that. double Exp (double d); - The number e raised to the power d. Find an approximation for e that matches your accuracy-requirements, and off you go.

Answer (score 6):

Would basic table with interpolation between values approach work? If ranges of values are limited (which is likely for your case - I doubt temperature readings have huge range) and high precisions is not required it may work. Should be easy to test on normal machine.

Here is one of many topics on table representation of functions: [Calculating vs. lookup tables for sine value performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382322/calculating-vs-lookup-tables-for-sine-value-performance)

Comment: the range of temperature is -22F to 158F (-30C to 70C) with 0.1F increment. there is 1800 possible temperature points and i guess a lookup table isn't enough.

Comment: @Donotalo, It still may be an option to try (also may not work for your needed precision) - both exp/ln functions are continuous, so you may need much less points for required precision of the result. I don't see temperature directly used as argument of exp/ln in the formula, so actual ranges for arguments are different - it is hard to predict if sparse table would work.

Answer (score 2):

Possible computation of ln(x) and expo(x) in C without `<math.h>` :

```c
static double expo(double n) {
    int a = 0, b = n > 0;
    double c = 1, d = 1, e = 1;
    for (b || (n = -n); e + .00001 < (e += (d *= n) / (c *= ++a)););
    // approximately 15 iterations
    return b ? e : 1 / e;
}

static double native_log_computation(const double n) {
    // Basic logarithm computation.
    static const double euler = 2.7182818284590452354 ;
    unsigned a = 0, d;
    double b, c, e, f;
    if (n > 0) {
        for (c = n < 1 ? 1 / n : n; (c /= euler) > 1; ++a);
        c = 1 / (c * euler - 1), c = c + c + 1, f = c * c, b = 0;
        for (d = 1, c /= 2; e = b, b += 1 / (d * c), b - e/* > 0.0000001 */;)
            d += 2, c *= f;
    } else b = (n == 0) / 0.;
    return n < 1 ? -(a + b) : a + b;
}

static inline double native_ln(const double n) {
    //  Returns the natural logarithm (base e) of N.
    return native_log_computation(n) ;
}

static inline double native_log_base(const double n, const double base) {
    //  Returns the logarithm (base b) of N.
    return native_log_computation(n) / native_log_computation(base) ;
}
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##xVRda9swFH33r7i0dNhNnNhZS7s6TSlsgz40D2MPGwyMP6RW4MjFVsbK2r@@7F5JtuJmpWUMZrBl33t0dc85kovwpig2m/2ScSEZLC@XYK80zdeiUkKmMpPc39sLYDoFWSvIQK5XOWu8btZ1@qGbNZucxKezU7qPjt9FR8ezt8dHPfBq@fFqefX567C@kJz7ujq@CSnUveep@zuGk6Cs13nFQN2ylEIJoXhVZwrqxiY9r1WZEkUPAvbjrvb7LxnAT49WFJJ6P4doDDkOEhYQJTrTYwuMx2MozcBoMAiOy/k5PDyALzEayiDB9AiiSYRXDHPw8fMc/BIOz2nJKfgFvY5GWRAkganSMLVuJK5@gZPPoO8xiBHPEu9xl0slX2DylAF2j52PgZuE4NTxHKLA6zwikmi0ybOqZQbUFe/pJsSGdJqSwwHKFSfEZwwkQWk57cIPDXxO8DD8A5xgQ@7YYghxYJQvUVe6rQOoKFGirqMnS@bGJ659QsQInB2FtmO4So6lONqBDmByRjPRIrbVmvZshtjSxB61QAPpwm4XDzx1K6EzIyjQzM2@kEW1LhnMV5m6ndwuPBdpVVmJfCcmagp532tRgmKtSqv6xqevwJhjz8Mq@5GWghPxCPod6tO@EFonHFB/EiMiz4Rx3xns9tTAiyaTpa83704M/djSiXaMTbzBBJhDAVtC1rJVXbsF0UAEkZHBM6D7et10OPk8zNI2JRdu1oUNhS505l5Dmx0y0LUWvZruiNC1pbEe7IbQz7sGpcafIpVEnAGIFg4mccS/yb2xq6lPtfNT/5v@r6GfLpfv0@vLL@SpzR/Ayd97i5QQgc8XvO1x9SvcJfDCzbuwodCFztxraLP/2F0q@Rp3yaVVJuS2r/3htUyd@XrO5lfBq@ym3YTV6jc)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Crouching Kitten's answer which gave me inspiration, you can build a pseudo-recursive (at most 1 self-call) logarithm to avoid using polynomials. In pseudo code

```
ln(x) :=
If (x <= 0)
    return NaN
Else if (!(1 <= x < 2))
    return LN2 * b + ln(a)
Else
    return taylor_expansion(x - 1)
```

This is pretty efficient and precise since on [1; 2) the taylor series converges A LOT faster, and we get such a number 1 <= a < 2 with the first call to ln if our input is positive but not in this range.

You can find 'b' as your unbiased exponent from the data held in the float x, and 'a' from the mantissa of the float x (a is exactly the same float as x, but now with exponent biased_0 rather than exponent biased_b). LN2 should be kept as a macro in hexadecimal floating point notation IMO. You can also use http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/frexp.3.html for this.

Also, the trick

```
unsigned long tmp = *(ulong*)(&d);
```

for "memory-casting" double to unsigned long, rather than "value-casting", is very useful to know when dealing with floats memory-wise, as bitwise operators will cause warnings or errors depending on the compiler.

Comment: Nice idea to make use of the internal float representation. What is the reason for the  `- 1` at the Taylor expansion? The problem I see is that the mantissa is an integer, and not in the `[1; 2)` range, and the `frexp` actually makes some computation to normalize the value.

Comment: This is a simplified version of my code, I have some optimizations handy.
- the y = x - 1 <=> ln(1 + y) = ln(x) is used to call taylor_expansion as ln(1 + y) = ln(x) = taylor(y) = y - y^2/2 + y^3/3... It's just an ease of implementation, but it's true it might be a little confusing at first.

Comment: - I also have an **else if (1.9 <= x < 2) return ln(x * 2 / 3) + ln (3/2);** clause to prevent numbers extremely close to their ceiling from making the function time out (try the algorithm with a value like 1e+23 (which is closer to 9.9999999999999e+22), you'll see without this small fix some cases are apocalyptically slow. Note that I keep 2/3 and ln(3/2) as macro hexadecimal floating point constants.) Gotta get that log to converge ! x)

Comment: - as for frexp, I go homemade: 
=> `u64 extract = *(u64*)(&d)`;
=> `norm = (extract & (0x8000000000000000 | 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF)) | 0x3FF0000000000000;` and `d = *(double*)(&norm);` for my normalized fraction (exp == 0)
=> `exp = ((extract << 1) >> 53) - 1023` for my exponent. 
You can check for other special values as well when starting your log (ie, +inf returns +inf, 1. returns 0., etc). Note that => serve to signify a \n in my comment plaintext here xd

Answer (score 1):

There is a really simple way to compute log<sub>2</sub> bit-by-bit. It is "efficient" in the way that it only requires basic integer operations and has no dependencies.  Below you find a go at it in C99. It is written in one chunk, but in practice you would split the code into header, C-file and `main.c` as is indicated in the code.

It implements three functions:

```cpp
// Input:  x       in [1, 2) in Q-Format 1.15.
// Output: log2(x) in [0, 1) in Q-Format 0.16.
extern uint16_t simple_log2_Q15 (uint16_t x);
```

As said, it only uses integer arithmetic.  The implementation is so simple that it's immeadiately clear how to write it in assembly. It uses: multplication, addition, comparison and shift by constant offsets of unsigned 32-bit (or less) integers.

---

```cpp
// A wrapper for the above for convenience.  Can be used just like log2f()
// except that it expects an ordinary, positive number x as input.
float simple_log2f (float x);
```

This can be used during transition.  It uses `simple_log2_Q15` from above, [`frexpf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/frexpf), [`ldexpf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ldexpf), and float addition.

---

```cpp
void test_simple_log2f (void);
```

This is just for testing. You can run it on a host to get a feel for the approximation error.  With the default setting from the source, it expands 15 fractional bits of log<sub>2</sub>.

Running in [godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/b15qrTfG1), it prints:

```
error(simple_log2f) = 1.025200e-04 = 12.251807 bits
```

---

### Full Code (C99)

```cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This goes to simple-log2.h

#ifndef SIMPLE_LOG2_H
#define SIMPLE_LOG2_H

#include <stdint.h>

// Input:  x       in [1, 2) in Q-Format 1.15.
// Output: log2(x) in [0, 1) in Q-Format 0.16.
extern uint16_t simple_log2_Q15 (uint16_t x);

// Returns log2(x) where x > 0 is an ordinary number.
extern float simple_log2f (float x);

#endif /* SIMPLE_LOG2_H */

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This goes to simple-log2.c

// #include "simple-log2.h"

#define FBIT 15

// Number of computed fractional bits in the result of simple_log2_Q15().
// May range from 0...16.
#define N_BITS 15

// Input:  x       in [1, 2) in Q-Format 1.15.
// Output: log2(x) in [0, 1) in Q-Format 0.16.
uint16_t simple_log2_Q15 (uint16_t x)
{
    const uint32_t Two = UINT32_C (0x80000000);

    // Expand N_BITS fractional bits of logarithmus dualis one by one.
    uint16_t ld = 0;

    for (uint8_t i = 1; i <= N_BITS; ++i)
    {
        ld <<= 1;

        // Squaring shifts log2(x) one bit to the left: log2(x^2) = 2 log2(x).
        // The result x2 stands in Q2.30, and log2(x^2) >= 1  iff  x2 >= 2.
        uint32_t x2 = (uint32_t) x * x;

        if (x2 >= Two)
        {
            // Shift FBITs to the right to convert from Q2.30 to Q1.15.
            // One additional shift subtracts 1 from log2(x).
            x = (uint16_t) (x2 >> (1 + FBIT));
            ld |= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // Shift FBITs to the right to convert from Q2.30 to Q1.15.
            x = (uint16_t) (x2 >> FBIT);
        }
    }

    // Return logarithmus dualis as Q0.16 in [0, 1).
    return ld << (16 - N_BITS);
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <math.h>
    
// A wrapper for the above for convenience.  Can be used just like log2f()
// except that it expects an ordinary, positive number x as input.
float simple_log2f (float x)
{
    // Decompose  x = mant * 2^ex  with mant in [0.5, 1).
    int ex;
    float mant = frexpf (x, &ex);

    // Turn mant in [0.5, 1) into Q-format 1.15 in [1, 2).  This introduces
    // a multiplication by 2, which we will account for at the end.
    uint16_t mantQ15 = (uint16_t) ldexpf (mant, FBIT + 1);

    // Compute log2(mant) in Q-format 0.16.
    uint16_t logQ16 = simple_log2_Q15 (mantQ15);

    // Turn Q0.16 back into float. "ex - 1" to undo the mul-by-2 from above.
    return (ex - 1) + ldexpf ((float) logQ16, -FBIT - 1);
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is for testing only and goes to, say, main.c.

// #include "simple-log2.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void test_simple_log2f (void)
{
    float max_dy = 0;
    float step_x = ldexpf (1.0f, -17);

    for (float x = 0.5f; x <= 2.5f; x += step_x)
    {
        float y = simple_log2f (x);
        float dy = fabsf (y - logf (x) / logf (2.0f));
        if (dy > max_dy)
            max_dy = dy;
    }

    printf ("error(simple_log2f) = %e = %f bits\n", max_dy, -1-log2f (max_dy));
}


int main (void)
{
    test_simple_log2f ();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off @Crouching Kitten's great natural log answer above, if you need it to be accurate for inputs <1 you can add a simple scaling factor. Below is an example in C++ that i've used in microcontrollers. It has a scaling factor of 256 and it's accurate to inputs down to 1/256 = ~0.04, and up to 2^32/256 = 16777215 (due to overflow of a uint32 variable).

It's interesting to note that even on an STMF103 Arm M3 with no FPU, the float implementation below is significantly faster (eg 3x or better) than the 16 bit fixed-point implementation in libfixmath (that being said, this float implementation still takes a few thousand cycles so it's still not ~fast~)

```
#include <float.h>

float TempSensor::Ln(float y) 
{
    // Algo from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18454010
    // Accurate between (1 / scaling factor) < y < (2^32  / scaling factor). Read comments below for more info on how to extend this range

    float divisor, x, result;
    const float LN_2 = 0.69314718; //pre calculated constant used in calculations
    uint32_t log2 = 0;


    //handle if input is less than zero
    if (y <= 0)
    {
        return -FLT_MAX;
    }

    //scaling factor. The polynomial below is accurate when the input y>1, therefore using a scaling factor of 256 (aka 2^8) extends this to 1/256 or ~0.04. Given use of uint32_t, the input y must stay below 2^24 or 16777216 (aka 2^(32-8)), otherwise uint_y used below will overflow. Increasing the scaing factor will reduce the lower accuracy bound and also reduce the upper overflow bound. If you need the range to be wider, consider changing uint_y to a uint64_t
    const uint32_t SCALING_FACTOR = 256;
    const float LN_SCALING_FACTOR = 5.545177444; //this is the natural log of the scaling factor and needs to be precalculated

    y = y * SCALING_FACTOR; 
    
    uint32_t uint_y = (uint32_t)y;
    while (uint_y >>= 1) // Convert the number to an integer and then find the location of the MSB. This is the integer portion of Log2(y). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4970859/6630230
    {
        log2++;
    }

    divisor = (float)(1 << log2);
    x = y / divisor;    // FInd the remainder value between [1.0, 2.0] then calculate the natural log of this remainder using a polynomial approximation
    result = -1.7417939 + (2.8212026 + (-1.4699568 + (0.44717955 - 0.056570851 * x) * x) * x) * x; //This polynomial approximates ln(x) between [1,2]

    result = result + ((float)log2) * LN_2 - LN_SCALING_FACTOR; // Using the log product rule Log(A) + Log(B) = Log(AB) and the log base change rule log_x(A) = log_y(A)/Log_y(x), calculate all the components in base e and then sum them: = Ln(x_remainder) + (log_2(x_integer) * ln(2)) - ln(SCALING_FACTOR)

    return result;
}
```