# Python logarithm math strange result

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the explanation for this unexpected results in Python??!;

```
from math import *
>>>log(1000,10) ## expecting 3.0
2.9999999999999996
>>>1000**(1/3) ## expecting 10.0
9.999999999999998
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of Floating Point arithmetic! Get ready for a fun ride into hell!

Answer (score 0):

Basically value of these functions are calculated using some series. As python by default uses floating values, so it calculates values very precisely.
You can see this...

[Efficient implementation of natural logarithm (ln) and exponentiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799041/efficient-implementation-of-natural-logarithm-ln-and-exponentiation)
That`s why it gives these types of result.
You can use Fraction class from fractions to convert these values to integer.

https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html