# Issue with implementation of natural logarithm (ln) and exponentiation

Tags: c, microcontroller, natural-logarithm

I try to follow the topic "Efficient implementation of natural logarithm (ln) and exponentiation" to be able to implement a log function without math.h. The described algorithm works well for values between 1 and 2 (normalized values). However, if the values are not normalized and I follow the normalization instructions, then I get wrong values.

Link: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799041/efficient-implementation-of-natural-logarithm-ln-and-exponentiation)

If I follow the code with an exemplary integer value of 12510, I get the following results:

y = 12510 (0x30DE), log2 = 13, divisor = 26, x = 481,1538

```
float ln(float y) {
    int log2;
    float divisor, x, result;

    log2 = msb((int)y); // See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4970859/6630230
    divisor = (float)(1 << log2);
    x = y / divisor;    // normalized value between [1.0, 2.0]

    result = -1.7417939 + (2.8212026 + (-1.4699568 + (0.44717955 - 0.056570851 * x) * x) * x) * x;
    result += ((float)log2) * 0.69314718; // ln(2) = 0.69314718

    return result;
}
```

The expected result for x should be a normalized value of 1 < x < 2. However, I fail in this calculation, because the received result is 481,1538.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Post missing `msb()` code.

Comment: Code for the msb() function:

unsigned int v;
unsigned r = 0;

while (v >>= 1) {
    r++;
}
return r;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of curiosity, I tried to reproduce:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int msb(unsigned int v) {
  unsigned int r = 0;
  while (v >>= 1) r++;
  return r;
}

float ln(float y)
{
    int log2;
    float divisor, x, result;

    log2 = msb((int)y); // See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4970859/6630230
    printf("log2: %d\n", log2);
    divisor = (float)(1 << log2);
    printf("divisor: %f\n", divisor);
    x = y / divisor;    // normalized value between [1.0, 2.0]
    printf("x: %f\n", x);
    result = -1.7417939 + (2.8212026 + (-1.4699568 + (0.44717955 - 0.056570851 * x) * x) * x) * x;
    result += ((float)log2) * 0.69314718; // ln(2) = 0.69314718
    return result;
}

int main()
{
  printf("ln(12510): %f\n", ln(12510));
}
```

Output:

```
log2: 13
divisor: 8192.000000
x: 1.527100
ln(12510): 9.434252
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6369779f711e6528)

I just tried this in my Windows 7 Pocket calculator and got:

```
9.434283603460956823997266847405
```

[image: 9,434283603460956823997266847405]

The first 5 digits are identical. – The rest I would consider as rounding issues whithout knowing which one got closer.

However, there is a typo (or mistake) in the question:

> y = 12510 (0x30DE), log2 = 13, divisor = 26, x = 481,1538

`divisor = (float)(1 << log2);` with `log2 = 13` yields `8192`.

`log2 << 1` would result in `26`.

Just for fun, I changed the line into `divisor = (float)(log2 << 1);` and got the following output:

```
log2: 13
divisor: 26.000000
x: 481.153839
ln(12510): -2982522368.000000
```

So, this leaves me a bit puzzled:

The exposed code seems to be correct but the OP seems to have it interpreted (or resembled) wrong.

Comment: Thanks so much, I interpreted it in the way log2 <<1. Now its solved, thx!

Comment: it works for a log of a number around 1 but for less than 1, the accuracy decreases dramatically. have you any suggestions for this case?