# How to change the audio pich when playing back video?

Tags: c++, qt, audio, video, multimedia

I'm developing a video player for playing karaoke videos. One useful feature would be to change the key of a song while playing back. So how could I modify the audio stream of a video while playing back in a QT application? There seemed to be hardly any information about this.

Answer (score 1):

Audio signal processing is quite complex and I expect fairly mathematical. The question has previously been asked [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156192/programmatically-increase-the-pitch-of-an-array-of-audio-samples), so if you're going to want to do the actual processing yourself, reading that thread and following the links will be a good place to start.

If you're new to audio signal processing, you may be better searching for a library that does what you want, to include in your project.

Comment: Thanks! I'm familiar with the algorithm, but the problem is more related to qt: How to extract audio from video and how to mix the edited audio with the original video (in real time)?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve a Pitch Shift effect that you are looking for. I know You are working with c++ for your project but i think [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyzY_ZP54pA&feature=youtu.be) tutorial for a Max MSP patch will help you understand some of the basics of one Pitch Shift algorithm. I don't know how familiar you are with digital audio theory but a few things you will need to look into are [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform), and Generating sine waves in code. I personally still do not have a mathematical grasp on FFT works but if you know what it does it can help you understand how to deconsruct audio signals.

Good Luck, Happy Coding